# vim rand() is not deterministic. Is this expected?

Tags: random, vim

According to `:help rand()`,

> `rand([{expr}])`
>
> Return a **pseudo-random Number** generated with an xoshiro128**
>           algorithm using seed `{expr}`.  The returned number is 32 bits,
>           also on 64 bits systems, for consistency.
>           `{expr}` can be initialized by `srand()` and will be updated by
>           `rand()`.  If `{expr}` is omitted, an internal seed value is used
>           and updated.
>           
>           Examples:
>                   :echo rand()
>                   :let seed = srand()
>                   :echo rand(seed)
>                   :echo rand(seed) % 16  " random number 0 - 15

It doesn't explain **how** a seed is changed every time `rand()` is called, but I expected it to be deterministically altered because

1. C++'s `std::rand()` does so,
2. and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator) says

> A pseudorandom number generator (PRNG), also known as a **deterministic** random bit generator (DRBG), is an algorithm...

However, in the code below, the value of `a` is deterministic but the values of `b` are **not** deterministic; they take different values when you restart the script.

```
let seed = srand(0)
let a = rand(seed) "deterministic
let b = rand() "not deterministic (why?)
echo [a, b]

let seed = [0, 1, 2, 3]
let a = rand(seed) "deterministic
let b = rand() "not deterministic (why?)
echo [a, b]
```

Is this an expected behavior? I think the behavior contradicts the documentation.

---

Environments:

```
~ $ vi --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Apr 30 2020 13:32:36)
Included patches: 1-664
```

Comment: What makes you think it's non-deterministic? Algorithm is deterministic, seed is random, and the resulting sequence is pseudo-random. Everything is as usual.

Comment: @Matt The documentation says << `{expr}` can be initialized by `srand()` and will be updated by `rand()` >>. In my script, `{expr}` set by `srand()` is updated non-deterministically by `rand()` although `rand()` is not "please use a new random seed".

Comment: The last sentence from `:h rand()` says: "If {expr} is omitted, an internal seed value is used and updated".

Comment: @Matt Yes. The first call of `rand(srand())` sets the internal seed.

Comment: No, this means there are two seeds: your seed, and an internal one.

Comment: @Matt Why can we (uniquely) interpret as that?

Comment: It is obvious from the source code. If you find the documentation badly worded, you can open an issue in Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is badly written but the behavior is actually the expected one from the source code's perspective.

### Analysis

`rand()` is defined as `f_rand()` in `src/evalfunc.c`. From the snippet at the end of this answer, we know some things:

1. `f_rand()` has only two sets of `static` variables: `gx`, ..., `gw` and `initialized`.
2. `gx`, ..., `gw` are the internal seeds. Their values are touched and referenced **only when** `f_rand()` is called with no argument (i.e. when `argvars[0].v_type == VAR_UNKNOWN`).
3. `initialized` remembers if `f_rand()` has ever been called with no argument and it is also touched and referenced only when `f_rand()` is called with no argument.
4. When `f_rand()` is called with a seed,

   1. The value of the seed is used **once** and that is **not** saved as a `static` variable. In other words, the sentence "*`{expr}` can be initialized by `srand()` and will be updated by `rand()`*" in the documentation is nothing but a "lie"; `{expr}` is not remembered and thus not updated by the subsequent `f_rand()`.
   2. The value of the seed is updated in place via the pointers `lx`, ..., `lw`.

### Conclusion

1. The sentence

> `{expr}` can be initialized by `srand()` and will be updated by `rand()`

shall be modified to

> `{expr}` can be initialized by `srand()` and will be updated by `rand({expr})`. You may want to store a seed into a variable and pass it to `rand()` since `{expr}` is **not** remembered in the function.

2. If you need the deterministic `rand()`, do this:

```
let seed = srand(0)
let a = rand(seed) "The value of `seed` is changed in place.
let b = rand(seed) "ditto
echo [a, b]
```

### The Source Code of `rand()`

```c
#define ROTL(x, k) ((x << k) | (x >> (32 - k))) 
#define SPLITMIX32(x, z) ( \
    z = (x += 0x9e3779b9), \
    z = (z ^ (z >> 16)) * 0x85ebca6b, \
    z = (z ^ (z >> 13)) * 0xc2b2ae35, \
    z ^ (z >> 16) \
    )    
#define SHUFFLE_XOSHIRO128STARSTAR(x, y, z, w) \ 
    result = ROTL(y * 5, 7) * 9; \ 
    t = y << 9; \ 
    z ^= x; \ 
    w ^= y; \ 
    y ^= z, x ^= w; \ 
    z ^= t; \ 
    w = ROTL(w, 11); 

/*
 * "rand()" function
 */
    static void 
f_rand(typval_T *argvars, typval_T *rettv)
{

    list_T      *l = NULL;
    static UINT32_T     gx, gy, gz, gw;
    static int  initialized = FALSE;
    listitem_T  *lx, *ly, *lz, *lw; 
    UINT32_T    x, y, z, w, t, result;

    if (argvars[0].v_type == VAR_UNKNOWN)
    {    
        // When no argument is given use the global seed list.
        if (initialized == FALSE)
        {
            // Initialize the global seed list.
            init_srand(&x);

            gx = SPLITMIX32(x, z);
            gy = SPLITMIX32(x, z);
            gz = SPLITMIX32(x, z);
            gw = SPLITMIX32(x, z);
            initialized = TRUE;
        }

        SHUFFLE_XOSHIRO128STARSTAR(gx, gy, gz, gw); 
    }    
    else if (argvars[0].v_type == VAR_LIST)
    {    
        l = argvars[0].vval.v_list;
        if (l == NULL || list_len(l) != 4)
            goto theend;

        lx = list_find(l, 0L);
        ly = list_find(l, 1L);
        lz = list_find(l, 2L);
        lw = list_find(l, 3L);
        if (lx->li_tv.v_type != VAR_NUMBER) goto theend;
        if (ly->li_tv.v_type != VAR_NUMBER) goto theend;
        if (lz->li_tv.v_type != VAR_NUMBER) goto theend;
        if (lw->li_tv.v_type != VAR_NUMBER) goto theend;
        x = (UINT32_T)lx->li_tv.vval.v_number;
        y = (UINT32_T)ly->li_tv.vval.v_number;
        z = (UINT32_T)lz->li_tv.vval.v_number;
        w = (UINT32_T)lw->li_tv.vval.v_number;

        SHUFFLE_XOSHIRO128STARSTAR(x, y, z, w);

        lx->li_tv.vval.v_number = (varnumber_T)x;
        ly->li_tv.vval.v_number = (varnumber_T)y;
        lz->li_tv.vval.v_number = (varnumber_T)z;
        lw->li_tv.vval.v_number = (varnumber_T)w;
    }
    else
        goto theend;

    rettv->v_type = VAR_NUMBER;
    rettv->vval.v_number = (varnumber_T)result;
    return;

theend:
    semsg(_(e_invarg2), tv_get_string(&argvars[0]));
    rettv->v_type = VAR_NUMBER;
    rettv->vval.v_number = -1;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

An algorithm used in Vim is fully deterministic. What creates a confusion is the fact that calling `rand(seed)` updates the seed "in place", but does not update any internal value(s). Therefore any subsequent `rand()` uses another (more or less random - quality depends on platform) internal seed value. So if you want to produce fully deterministic sequence, you must consequently invoke `rand(seed)` with the same variable.

This behaviour is easy to deduce from Vim's source code. Also `:h rand()` says that:

> Return a pseudo-random Number generated with an xoshiro128**
>   algorithm using seed {expr}.  The returned number is 32 bits,
>   also on 64 bits systems, for consistency.
>   {expr} can be initialized by srand() and will be updated by
>   rand().  **If {expr} is omitted, an internal seed value is used
>   and updated.**

If you find the wording misleading you can open an issue on github.